# How to parse list-Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to get EBS volumes ID so i can create LLD Zabbix discovery

https://github.com/omni-lchen/zabbix-cloudwatch/blob/master/awsLLD.py

```
def getEBS(a, r):
    account = a
    aws_account = awsAccount(account)
    aws_access_key_id = aws_account._aws_access_key_id
    aws_secret_access_key = aws_account._aws_secret_access_key
    aws_region = r
    #component = c
    # Init LLD Data
    lldlist = []
    llddata = {"data":lldlist}

    # Connect to EC2 service
    conn = awsConnection()
    conn.ebsConnect(aws_region, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
    ebsConn = conn._aws_connection

    # Save EBS function results in a list

    functionResultsList = []

    # Save volume names in a list

    tdata = []

    # Get a list of EBS volumes

    functionResults = ebsConn.get_all_volumes()
```

output:

```
[Volume:vol-029213f06d66eadac, Volume:vol-00fbd5dfaebd79e83, Volume:vol-0eeb126d13ecf0eed, Volume:vol-09a1f3446b3f78ea5]
```

I'm having issues parsing above output to get

```
vol-029213f06d66eadac
vol-0eeb126d13ecf0eed
vol-09a1f3446b3f78ea5
```

I know i need to write something like:

```
for la in functionResultsList:
 print la[0]
```

getting first element
but don't know how to continue

Answer (score 0):

removed list and used:

```
 for la in range(len(functionResults)):

      print functionResults[la]
```

output:

```
Volume:vol-029213f06d66eadac
Volume:vol-00fbd5dfaebd79e83
Volume:vol-0eeb126d13ecf0eed
Volume:vol-09a1f3446b3f78ea5
```

New to python and don't know what's list actually- but i don't think it's reason for downwote